# Создание Foreground service Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

пытаюсь сделать foreground service. как указано здесь:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079610/how-to-create-a-xamarin-foreground-service#comment108058280_61079610

Но, служба даже не запускается, как я поняла, что мне стоит изменить или возможно написать все заново.

В комментариях там даны несколько вариантов, например добавить атрибут [Service], если не работает. Но, когда его добавляю мне дает NullReferenceException на первой строчке в OnStartCommand  в DataSource.

Что мне делать?

Я пыталась в виде теста сделать службу, которая будет записывать в файл время, а потом просто каждые две секунды выводить текст файла в label, но файл всегда пустой
Вот мой код:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(AndroidServiceHelper))]
namespace App6.Droid
{
  internal class AndroidServiceHelper : IAndroidService
  {
    private static Context context = global::Android.App.Application.Context;

    public void StartService()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(DataSource));
        
        if(Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            context.StartForegroundService(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            context.StartService(intent);
        }
    }

    public void StopService()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(DataSource));
        context.StopService(intent);
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
namespace App6
{
    public interface IAndroidService
    {
       void StartService();
       void StopService();
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace App6.Droid
{
internal class NotificationHelper : INotification
{
    public static string foregroundChannelId = "9001";
    private static Context context = global::Android.App.Application.Context;
    public Notification ReturnNotif()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
        intent.PutExtra("Title", "Message");

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        var notifBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, foregroundChannelId)
            .SetContentTitle("Your Title")
            .SetContentText("Main Text Body")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notify_panel_notification_icon_bg)
            .SetOngoing(true)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        // Building channel if API verion is 26 or above
        if (global::Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(foregroundChannelId, "Title", NotificationImportance.High);
            notificationChannel.Importance = NotificationImportance.High;
            notificationChannel.EnableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.EnableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.SetShowBadge(true);
            notificationChannel.SetVibrationPattern(new long[] { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400 });

            var notifManager = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            if (notifManager != null)
            {
                notifBuilder.SetChannelId(foregroundChannelId);
                notifManager.CreateNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
        }

        return notifBuilder.Build();
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
namespace App6
{
   public interface INotification
   {
      Notification ReturnNotif();
   }
}
```

---

```
namespace App6
{
public class DataSource : Service
{
    private string path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "s.txt");
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public const int ServiceRunningNotifID = 9000;

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Notification notif = DependencyService.Get<INotification>().ReturnNotif();
        StartForeground(ServiceRunningNotifID, notif);
        Proccesing();

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
    
    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    public override bool StopService(Intent name)
    {
        return base.StopService(name);
    }
    public void Proccesing()
    {
       using(StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
    }


  }
}
```

---

```
namespace App6
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "s.txt");
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DependencyService.Get<IAndroidService>().StartService();
        Timer timer = new Timer((o) =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>  label1.Text = File.ReadAllText(path));
        }, null, 2000, 2000);
    }
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже разобралась сама, надо было написать

`[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(NotificationHelper))]`

над классом NotificationHelper и добавить строчку
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />`
в манифест